# Unit testing for appconfig service which gets json file in angular 9

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular9

I have recently started learning unit testing in angular and currently trying to write tests for appconfig service.

The Code which I want to unit test for appservice config is as below, which gets the environments from the json file:

```
public loadEnvironment(): Observable<AppSettings> {
    if (!this.configuration$) {
      this.configuration$ = this.http.get<AppSettings>(`/environment`).pipe(
        shareReplay(1)
      );
    }
    return this.configuration$;
  }
```

For this, I tried to write below test but somehow I am not able to figure out how I can mock the json file get here?

```
describe('AppConfigService', () => {
  let appConfigService: AppConfigService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        AppConfigService
      ],
    });

    appConfigService = TestBed.get(AppConfigService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it(`should fetch enviornment as an Observable`, async(inject([HttpTestingController, AppConfigService],
    (httpClient: HttpTestingController, appConfigService: AppConfigService) => {

      appConfigService.loadEnvironment().subscribe();

      let req = httpMock.expectOne('/environment');
      expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");

      httpMock.verify();
    })));
});
```

As I said I am very new so please consider that.